# how to transfer IOS to router cisco

Tags: show-desktop

I would like to know how to install and configure tftp on ubuntu desktop 16.04
to upload a IOS to Cisco Router and to backup the IOS from Router.

Thanks
Fernando Ag

Comment: Eh. Don't you do that -from- the router itself?  I think it was called "xmodem"(?)

Comment: "Xmodem" is not the correct way to backup and upload IOS on Cisco Router.

On Windows SO with "TFTPd" is very simple, I just want to know if there is "TFTP" on Linux "Ubuntu"?